# Is there any way to extract value list from map in presto query?

Tags: sql, dictionary, presto

i have table with a column that has two columns: ID (bigint), Vals (map<bigint, float>).

```
123134    {"0":0.234, "1":-431.4358, "2":58.213, "3":6.124, ... "99":-32.123}
```

The bigint keys for Vals are just 0, 1, 2, ..., 99

I just need to extract float values from this column using presto SQL per each ID. For instance, in the above example, for the ID: 123134, I just need the following:

```
    [0.345, -431.4358, 58.213, 6.124, ..., -32.123]
```

As of now, the only way I could think of doing it is the following:

```
   select ID, ARRAY[vals[0], vals[1], vals[2], ..., vals[99]] from table
```

However, this seems super inefficient.

Is there a smart way of doing it?

Any help or reference would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`unnest`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html?highlight=unnest) to turn map into rows and [`map_values`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/map.html) to get values as an array:

```
with a(id, sample) as (
  select 1,
    map(
      array[1,2,3],
      array[0.123, 1.234,23.45]
    )
  union all
  
  select 2,
    map(
      array[6,7],
      array[123.4,567]
    )
)
select
  a.id,
  map_values(a.sample) as vals,
  t.k,
  t.val
from a
  cross join unnest(a.sample) as t(k,val)
```

| # | id | vals | k | val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | [123.4, 567.0] | 6 | 123.4 |
| 2 | 2 | [123.4, 567.0] | 7 | 567.0 |
| 3 | 1 | [0.123, 1.234, 23.45] | 1 | 0.123 |
| 4 | 1 | [0.123, 1.234, 23.45] | 2 | 1.234 |
| 5 | 1 | [0.123, 1.234, 23.45] | 3 | 23.45 |

Comment: My apologies. I just modified the question. For this one, I would need

ID                          val 
1                      [0.123, 1.234, 23.45]
2                   [123.4, 567.0]

is there a way of doing that?

Comment: @user98235 Yes, I've updated my answer with a function to get values as an array

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but do you mind taking a look at stackoverflow.com/questions/76169414/… ? Thanks